# LocalHost not reloading and crashing on save

Tags: javascript, reactjs, crash, localhost

So I am building a huge project in React.Js and VSCode, and I have had no problems up to this point.

Recently when dealing with this json object, my program (on localhost:3000) just won't save, and then when I refresh the page, it just crashes.

I can't even close the tab when this happens. It's just frozen in refreshing. I have to Ctl + ALt+ Del to shut it down. It seems like it is happening randomly.

I am using Google Chrome.

What is going wrong? What do I do? Thank you.

```
    for (var obj in json1) {
      const json = json1[obj];
      for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
        const apt = json[i];
        // Do some stuff with the big json object
      }
    }
```

Comment: I don't see any react specific code yet you tagged the question with react. You may be stuck in an infinite loop or doing lots of re renders. Usually the browser will ask you to stop the script unless you're doing something asynchronous but I don't see that in the code you are posting. Also; welcome to SO, you can use `@` to respond to particular comments.

Comment: Depending on the size of the dataset it could just be really slow considering you are doing a loop within a loop. Can you post what the data looks like? Also, the  `// Do some stuff with the big json object` could be relevant.